# How can I tell Athena to generate a CSV output using Insert Into?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I want to leverage `INSERT INTO` to create CSV files in S3 at specific partition paths. For example,

```
INSERT INTO "destinationdb"."destinationtable" (
col1,
col2,
col3,
partition_col_1,
partition_col_2,
partition_col_3
)
(
SELECT col1, col2, col3, partition_col_1, partition_col_2, partition_col_3
FROM "sourcedb"."sourcetable"
)
```

And lets say I configure `destinationdb.destinationtable` to be an athena table with `partition_col_1`, `partition_col_2`, and `partition_col_3` as partition columns. And I want `destinationdb.destinationtable` to point to `s3://mybucket/destinationtable/partition_col_1/partition_col_2/partition_col_3/`. Then, every time I run the INSERT INTO, I want to generate a CSV file at this s3 path.

Will this work?